# Getting only two processes to execute code in MPI - don't know which processes will get to code segment though

Tags: c, mpi

I have a MPI program in C.  There is a part of the program where an arbitrary number processes could reach.  I just want 2 processes to do something and I want the rest not to do anything.  It is unknown which process ids will reach this part of the program so I CAN'T do this:

```
if(rank == 0 || rank == 1) { 
  // do something
}
// (else do nothing)
```

The rank-0 and rank-1 process may never reach here though.  I do know that **at least** two processes will reach here though.

How can this be achieved in MPI?

Many thanks :).

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the basic problem is?  Why would it be bad for more than 2 processes to do the one thing?  The extra cost to have "extra" processes doing some task might be less than the synchronization cost necessary to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Start two processes seperately that you must code to reach there, and then use the rank determination.

EDIT: Make a shared integer across all proccesses that one process will increment when it reaches that patch of code and so will the next process, and mark the code in question with a if condition so it won't run unless this shared integer, is less than 2.

Comment: Nope can't do that!  I start a set number of processes, they all start doing the exact same thing and gradually start branching off making different choices.  Due to this branching, I don't know which processes will get to this function.  Sorry.. good idea but not for my problem.

Comment: In the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948788/creating-a-counter-that-stays-synchronized-across-mpi-processes there is code for implementing a counter like this.

Answer (score 2):

Setup Rank `0` (or Rank `n-1`) as a "control rank". This rank will hold the two magic tokens to control entry into the critical section.

Use an `MPI_IRecv` on `MPI_ANY_SOURCE`. Every rank that reached the critical code section will `MPI_Send` to rank 0 to ID themselves as having reached the critical section.  Then rank 0 will `MPI_Send` and the rank at the critical section will `MPI_Recv` a token. The first two ranks to reach the critical code will be sent a "go ahead" token. Send any other ranks a "don't bother" token.

At the end of the run, there will be one unmatched `MPI_IRecv`. This `MPI_Irecv` can be cancelled prior to entering `MPI_Finalize`.