# How to replicate the function of MPI_Accumulate in MPI-2+

Tags: c++, mpi, communication, mpi-rma

I am learning MPI one sided communications introduced in MPI-2/MPI-3, and came across this [online course page](http://www.cac.cornell.edu/Ranger/MPIoneSided/accumulate.aspx) about `MPI_Accumulate`:

> MPI_Accumulate allows the caller to combine the data moved to the
>   target process with data already present, such as accumulation of a
>   sum at a target process. The same functionality could be achieved by
>   using MPI_Get to retrieve data (followed by synchronization);
>   performing the sum operation at the caller; then using MPI_Put to send
>   the updated data back to the target process. Accumulate simplifies
>   this messiness ...

But there are only a limited number of operations that are allowed to be used with `MPI_Accumulate` (max, min, sum, product etc.), and user-defined operations are not allowed. I was wondering how to implement the above mentioned ***messiness***, using `MPI_Get`, sync, op, and `MPI_Put`. Are there any tutorials or working code examples in C/C++?

Thanks

---

In order to test, I adapted the a piece of code from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948788/creating-a-counter-that-stays-synchronized-across-mpi-processes), in which one sided communication is used to create an integer counter that is kept synchronized across MPI processes. The target problem line using `MPI_Accumulate` is marked.

The code compiles as is and returns in about 15 seconds. But when I tried to replace `MPI_Accumulate` with an equivalent sequence of basic operations as shown in the comment block immediately after the problem line, the compiled program hangs indefinitely.

Can anyone please help explain what went wrong, and 
what's the right way to replace `MPI_Accumulate` in this context?

P.S. I compiled the code with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I..   mpistest.cpp -lmpi
```

and executed the binary with

```
mpiexec -n 4 a.exe
```

---

Code:

```
//adpated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948788/
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct mpi_counter_t {
  MPI_Win win;
  int  hostrank;  //id of the process that host values to be exposed to all processes
  int  rank;    //process id
  int  size;     //number of processes
  int  val;      
  int  *hostvals; 
};

struct mpi_counter_t *create_counter(int hostrank) {
    struct mpi_counter_t *count;

    count = (struct mpi_counter_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct mpi_counter_t));
    count->hostrank = hostrank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(count->rank));
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(count->size));

    if (count->rank == hostrank) {
        MPI_Alloc_mem(count->size * sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, &(count->hostvals));
        for (int i=0; i<count->size; i++) count->hostvals[i] = 0;
        MPI_Win_create(count->hostvals, count->size * sizeof(int), sizeof(int),
                       MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(count->win));
    } 
    else {
        count->hostvals = NULL;
        MPI_Win_create(count->hostvals, 0, 1,
                       MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(count->win));
    }
    count -> val = 0;

    return count;
}

int increment_counter(struct mpi_counter_t *count, int increment) {
    int *vals = (int *)malloc( count->size * sizeof(int) );
    int val;

    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, count->hostrank, 0, count->win);

    for (int i=0; i<count->size; i++) {

        if (i == count->rank) {
        MPI_Accumulate(&increment, 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM,count->win); //Problem line: increment hostvals[i] on host
        /* //Question: How to correctly replace the above MPI_Accumulate call with the following sequence? Currently, the following causes the program to hang.
            MPI_Get(&vals[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, count->win);
            MPI_Win_fence(0,count->win);
            vals[i] += increment;
            MPI_Put(&vals[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, count->win);
            MPI_Win_fence(0,count->win);
        //*/
        } else {
            MPI_Get(&vals[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, count->win);
        }
    }

    MPI_Win_unlock(0, count->win);

    //do op part of MPI_Accumulate's work on count->rank
    count->val += increment; 
    vals[count->rank] = count->val; 

    //return the sum of vals
    val = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<count->size; i++)
        val += vals[i];

    free(vals);
    return val;
}

void delete_counter(struct mpi_counter_t **count) {
    if ((*count)->rank == (*count)->hostrank) {
        MPI_Free_mem((*count)->hostvals);
    }
    MPI_Win_free(&((*count)->win));
    free((*count));
    *count = NULL;

    return;
}

void print_counter(struct mpi_counter_t *count) {
    if (count->rank == count->hostrank) {
        for (int i=0; i<count->size; i++) {
            printf("%2d ", count->hostvals[i]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    const int WORKITEMS=50;

    struct mpi_counter_t *c;
    int rank;
    int result = 0;

    c = create_counter(0);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    srand(rank);

    while (result < WORKITEMS) {
        result = increment_counter(c, 1);
        if (result <= WORKITEMS) {
             printf("%d working on item %d...\n", rank, result);
         std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(rand()%2));
         } else {
             printf("%d done\n", rank);
         }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    print_counter(c);
    delete_counter(&c);


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

One additional question, should I use `MPI_Win_fence` here instead of locks?

--EDIT--

I used lock/unlock in `increment_counter` as follows, the program runs but behaves strangely. In the final print out, the master node does all the work. Still confused.

```
int increment_counter(struct mpi_counter_t *count, int increment) {
    int *vals = (int *)malloc( count->size * sizeof(int) );
    int val;

    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, count->hostrank, 0, count->win);

    for (int i=0; i<count->size; i++) {

        if (i == count->rank) {
            //MPI_Accumulate(&increment, 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM,count->win); //Problem line: increment hostvals[i] on host
            ///* //Question: How to correctly replace the above MPI_Accumulate call with the following sequence? reports that 0 does all the work
            MPI_Get(&vals[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, count->win);
            MPI_Win_unlock(0, count->win);
            vals[i] += increment;
            MPI_Put(&vals[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, count->win);
            MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, count->hostrank, 0, count->win);
        //*/
        } else {
            MPI_Get(&vals[i], 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, count->win);
        }
    }

    MPI_Win_unlock(0, count->win);

    //do op part of MPI_Accumulate's work on count->rank
    count->val += increment; 
    vals[count->rank] = count->val; 

    //return the sum of vals
    val = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<count->size; i++)
        val += vals[i];

    free(vals);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Locks are finer-grained than fences (which are collective), so it's good to use them where you can.  But be careful of nested synchronization!  You've got fences inside a region that is already locked and so you're hanging.  Also note that MPI-3, which came out after that question/answer, has greatly improved one-sided routines and semantics..

Comment: @JonathanDursi Thanks. I've tried lock/unlocks. It still does not give the correct result. Please see the EDIT.

Comment: The MPI-3.0 standard improved the routines and semantics. The existing implementations didn't :)

Comment: If this case is too complicated for explanation, I have asked a question simpler case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728083/ , where there is only one "global" value used to keep record of the "minimum" value among processes. I have some sync issues even in the simpler case.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Accumulate with Gets and Puts is indeed going to be very messy, particularly when you have to deal with derived datatypes and such.  But assuming you are doing an accumulate on a single integer, and you want to just sum up a local value into a remote buffer, you can do the following (pseudo-code only):

```
MPI_Win_lock(EXCLUSIVE);  /* exclusive needed for accumulate atomicity constraints */
MPI_Get(&remote_data);
MPI_Win_flush(win);  /* make sure GET has completed */
new = local_data + remote_data;
MPI_Put(&new);
MPI_Win_unlock();
```

Your code is incorrect because you are giving up the exclusive lock after the GET, which causes atomicity issues when two processes are trying to sum data simultaneously.