# order issue in sychronizing MPI-2 one sided communication

Tags: c++, synchronization, mpi, mpi-rma

I am learning MPI-2 and trying to implement the first simple functionality using MPI-2 one-sided-communication:

Have process 0 host one array of fixed size `data_size`.

Each process (including 0) will generate an array and compare with the host array:

If the first element of the generated array is smaller than that of the host array, replace the host array with the generated one.

In code:

```
vector<int> v1 = {rank,rank+1,rank+2};
v = get_vec(vec);
if (v1[0] < v[0])
    put_vec(vec,v1);
```

The complete code is at the bottom. I expect, of course, that out of all generated arrays, the one with the smallest head element should be in the host array finally when program finishes, because the smallest array ([0,1,2] in this example) will replace others and will not be replaced itself.

However, in some (rare) occasions, I got output like this:

```
$ mpiexec.exe -n 4 a.exe
#0 assigns v1 {0 ...} to host v {2 ...}
#1 assigns v1 {1 ...} to host v {2 ...}
 1  2  3
```

, which seems to show that two assignments are made at the same time to the host data. I guess I must have misunderstood the lock/unlock synchronization directives in `get_vec/putvec` or made some obvious mistakes elsewhere.

Can some one please explain how should I fixed my code to get the expected output?

Thanks in advance.

---

Complete Code compiled using `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lmpi`:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


struct mpi_vector_t {
  MPI_Win win;
  int  hostrank;  //id of the process that host values to be exposed to all processes
  int  rank;    //process id
  int  size;     //number of processes
  int  *data;
  int  data_size;
};

struct mpi_vector_t *create_vec(int hostrank, std::vector<int> v) {
    struct mpi_vector_t *vec;

    vec = (struct mpi_vector_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct mpi_vector_t));
    vec->hostrank = hostrank;
    vec->data_size = v.size();
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(vec->rank));
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(vec->size));

    if (vec->rank == hostrank) {
        MPI_Alloc_mem(vec->data_size * sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, &(vec->data));
        for (int i=0; i<vec->size; i++) vec->data[i] = v[i];
        MPI_Win_create(vec->data, vec->data_size * sizeof(int), sizeof(int),
                       MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(vec->win));
    }
    else {
        vec->data = NULL;
        vec->data_size = v.size();
        MPI_Win_create(vec->data, 0, 1,
                       MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &(vec->win));
    }
    return vec;
}

void delete_vec(struct mpi_vector_t **count) {
    if ((*count)->rank == (*count)->hostrank) {
        MPI_Free_mem((*count)->data);
    }
    MPI_Win_free(&((*count)->win));
    free((*count));
    *count = NULL;

    return;
}

std::vector<int> get_vec(struct mpi_vector_t *vec) {
    vector<int> ret(vec->data_size);
    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_SHARED, vec->hostrank, 0, vec->win);
    MPI_Get(&ret.front(), vec->data_size, MPI_INT, vec->hostrank, 0, vec->data_size, MPI_INT, vec->win);
    MPI_Win_unlock(0, vec->win);
    return ret;
}

void put_vec(struct mpi_vector_t *vec, std::vector<int> v) {
    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, vec->hostrank, 0, vec->win);
    MPI_Put(&v.front(), vec->data_size, MPI_INT, vec->hostrank, 0, vec->data_size, MPI_INT, vec->win);
    MPI_Win_unlock(0, vec->win);
}

void print_vec(struct mpi_vector_t *vec) {
    if (vec->rank == vec->hostrank) {
        for (int i=0; i<vec->data_size; i++) {
            printf("%2d ", vec->data[i]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    struct mpi_vector_t *vec;
    int rank;

    vector<int> v = {2,3,1};
    vec = create_vec(0, v);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    for (int itest = 0; itest < 2; itest++) {
        vector<int> v1 = { rank, rank + 1, rank + 2 }; //some generated data
        v = get_vec(vec);
        if (v1[0] < v[0]) {
            cout << "#" << rank << " assigns v1 {" << v1[0] <<
                    " ...} to host v {" << v[0] << " ...}" << endl;
            put_vec(vec, v1);
        }
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    print_vec(vec);
    delete_vec(&vec);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical data race scenario. Both `get_vec` and `put_vec` lock the window individually, but you actually need is a lock that spans the whole code block, i.e.:

```
lock_window();
v = get_vec(vec);
if (v1[0] < v[0])
   put_vec(vec,v1);
unlock_window();
```

As it currently stands, it is possible that the content of the shared vector could change right after the call to `get_vec()` because another process has executed `put_vec()` and that could invalidate the result of the comparison. Something like this:

```
std::vector<int> compare_swap_vec(struct mpi_vector_t *vec, std::vector v) {
    vector<int> ret(vec->data_size);
    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, vec->hostrank, 0, vec->win_ext);
    ret = get_vec(vec);
    if (v[0] < ret[0])
        put_vec(vec, v);
    MPI_Win_unlock(0, vec->win_ext);
    return ret;
}
```

The function `compare_swap_vec()` takes a vector and uses it to replace the old content of the shared vector if the less-than relation holds. It also returns the previous content of the vector. `vec->win_ext` is another window hosted by the same process that hosts the vector content. It is used for the outer lock since the MPI standard requires that distinct access epochs for the same window at the same process must be disjoint, which I interpret as that nested locks on the same window are not allowed.

Comment: You are completely right. But did one-sided communication specifically require a synchronization operation after a `MPI_Get` call before you use the retrieved content in `MPI_Put` (to wait for the asyc. op to finish)? Or did MPI-2 says somewhere this combination should be OK? Thanks.

Comment: While my note on having to lock the window for the duration of both calls is correct, I've missed the fact that both `MPI_Get` and `MPI_Put` are non-blocking and they are guaranteed to complete only at the end of the access epoch, which means that the outer lock has to be on a different window. You can probably utilise this [MPI-2 mutex implementation](https://gist.github.com/aprell/1486197).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. I don't know enough about mutex now, but I believe that's the right direction.